# Bootstrap - Making the inline form select longer

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm having an issue with my selects, whenever I put in the "form-inline" class on them, their length goes down by a lot

[image]

[image]

```
<div class="col">
    <div class="form-group form-inline">
        <label for="boatType">Boat Type </label>
        <select class="form-control" id="boatType">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I fix this so that it takes up the length of the entire column?

Comment: Why don't you use grid?

Comment: Isn't columns inside rows using the grid? I cut that out but this is a column which is in a row

Comment: No problem. It'll become nested row i.e. row inside another column.

Answer (score 0):

You could write custom css:

```
.form-group.form-inline label,
.form-group.form-inline select {
  flex: 1;
}
```

(assuming you are using bootstrap 4 and form-inline will set display: flex; already)

Answer (score 0):

You can use grid,

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="boatType" class="col-3 col-form-label">Boat Type </label>
  <div class="col-9">
    <select class="form-control" id="boatType">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or flex,

```
<div class="form-group d-flex">
  <label for="boatType" class="col-form-label">Boat Type </label>
  <div class="flex-grow-1">
    <select class="form-control" id="boatType">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x2akmg